# Цивильный и цивилизованный? Разница в значениях

Tags: грамматика, заимствования

Насколько значения этих слов отличаются одно от другого? Насколько я знаю, хоть у этих двух слов и имеется общий корень, всё же значения разные. Но зачастую можно слышать слово "цивильный" в значении "приличный", что от его словарного значения "гражданский", согласитесь, довольно далеко. Будет ли грамотно сказать, к примеру, следующую фразу: "Этот городок оказался вполне **цивильным**, экзотическим, а не таким ужасным, как его обычно рисует наше воображение"?
И не будет ли уместнее употребить в данном контексте слово "цивилизованным"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Будет ли грамотно сказать, к примеру, следующую фразу: "Этот городок оказался вполне цивильным, экзотическим, а не таким ужасным, как его обычно рисует наше воображение"?

Вполне. Тут нет значения "приличный" (если, конечно, автор употребил слово осознано, а не как вы подозреваете - по причине ошибочного понимания). "Цивильный" здесь может означать наличие гражданских объектов, инфраструктуры. "Цивилизованный" - было бы неточно.

> И не будет ли уместнее употребить в данном контексте слово "цивилизованным"?

Именно в этом - вряд ли. Хотя вообще-то "цивильный" - частичный синоним "цивилизованному", в каких-то случаях они вполне взаимозамещаемы, и по соображениям стилистики "цивилизованный" может оказаться предпочтительным. Например: цивилизованные земли (=окультуренные), здесь "цивильные" звучало бы хуже и подлежало бы замене.

ЦИВИЛЬНЫЙ, -ая, -ое. [лат. civilis - гражданский] Разг. Гражданский, штатский; отвечающий требованиям цивилизации (2 зн.). Ц. костюм (достаточно модный, приличный). Ц-ые отношения. Разойдёмся, как подобает цивильным людям. Пойдём в кафе, посидим в цивильной обстановке.
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x
(БТС)

Answer (score 2):

Лучший вариант: Этот городок оказался вполне **цивильным,** экзотическим, а не таким ужасным, как его обычно рисует наше воображение.

**Цивильный** (разг.) -  отвечающий требованиям цивилизации, разговорная оценка.

**Цивилизованный** - приобщенный к цивилизации, книжное слово с обобщенным значением (цивилизованное общество, мир).